# Is it normal that scatterplot and residual (Anscombe) plot have the same shape but translated?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, programming

I'm using R to produce a scatterplot and a residual (anscombe) plot. However I got something really weird. As you can see below.

Here is the scatter plot:
[image: scatter]
And here is the residual:
[image: residual]

As you can see they have the same exact shape, but they are just moved. Is this normal in a simple linear regression context?

**Code**

I am pretty confident of my code, but anyway, to take away any doubt this is a Minimal Example of my code:

```
# Plot the scatter plot, where x is the explanatory variable, y the response
plot(data$x, data$y)
# Fit linear model
data.lm <- lm( y ~x, data=data)
# Create standardized residuals
data.lm$sr <- rstandard(data.lm)
# Plot the Residual Plot
plot(data.lm$fitted.values, data.lm$sr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not have the exact same shape. Three of the data points appear to be at about $(40,40),$ $(42,43),$ and $(44,42).$ Look at their images in the residual plot and you can see that the angles in the triangle have changed.

This is not a translation (which would preserve the shape) by a [shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping). When, as in this case, the correlation in the original scatterplot is close to $0$, then the change in shape will be small.

Now try this with these points: $(0,3) (0,6), (1,11), (1,12), (1,16).$ Look at the original plot and the residuals, and see what changes and what doesn't.

When you fit a straight line by least squares, the residual plot will always be a shear of the original scatterplot, for reasons that should become clear when you think about the relationship between the fitted line and the residuals.

Comment: Well we can write $r_i = \hat{\varepsilon}_i=y_i-\hat{y}_i$, but still don't see why it should be clear :/

Comment: @Euler_Salter : Think about the geometry of the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y-(\alpha+\beta x)).$ It is a shear. $\qquad$

Comment: but what you say should hold if we make a plot of the residuals against the explanatory variable! Instead the residual plot is a plot of the residuals against the fitted values. Hence shouldn't it be $(x,y) \mapsto (\alpha+\beta x, y-(\alpha +\beta x))$ ?

Comment: @Euler_Salter : Sorry -- I should have noticed that. But the vector of fitted values is still just an affine transformation of the vector of predictors. (One situation where this wouldn't apply is a multiple regression.)